# Kivy/python : How to check checkbox from a .py file

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have written some code in Python (test.py) and kivy (test.kv).
When I run `test.py` then male checkbox shows checked and female checkbox unchecked because I am using in `test.kv` file:

```
active: root.male
```

But I want the same thing from a .py file. How to checked male checkbox from a .py file?

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Window.size = (600, 325)

class UserGroup(Screen):
    male = ObjectProperty(None)
    female = ObjectProperty(None)
    age = ObjectProperty(None)

    def insert_data(self):
        print('')


class FactUserGroup(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FactUserGroup().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.120

UserGroup

    male: chk_male
    female: chk_female

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 20, 20
        row_default_height: '30dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Male'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id : chk_male
            active: root.male

        Label:
            text: 'Female'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id: chk_female


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use ***BooleanProperty***, and add ***active: root.female***. In the example it illustrates when the Kivy app is running the checkbox for female is active (Figure 1), after 5 seconds, it will automatically switch to the checkbox for male (Figure 2) using Clock.schedule_once.

### test.py

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty
...
class UserGroup(Screen):
    male = BooleanProperty(False)
    female = BooleanProperty(True)
```

### test.kv

```
    CheckBox:
        group: 'check'
        id: chk_female
        active: root.female
```

## Example

### test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.size = (600, 325)


class UserGroup(Screen):
    male = BooleanProperty(False)
    female = BooleanProperty(True)
    age = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UserGroup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.switch_checkbox, 5)

    def switch_checkbox(self, dt):
        self.female = False
        self.male = True

    def insert_data(self):
        print('')


class FactUserGroup(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FactUserGroup().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.120

UserGroup:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 20, 20
        row_default_height: '30dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Male'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id : chk_male
            active: root.male

        Label:
            text: 'Female'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id: chk_female
            active: root.female


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1 - CheckBox Female]
[image: Figure 2 - CheckBox Male after 5 minutes]

Comment: thank you so much.I am really sorry I can't vote because i have less than 15 reputation.When i cross 15 Reputation i will do vote.Thanks again